# All dates between two dates with 30 minutes intervals

Tags: php, datetime

i have $one = '2011-12-22 07:00 and $two = '2011-12-22 11:30';

i would like receive all data with 30 minutes interval. For this example should be:

```
2011-12-22 07:00
2011-12-22 07:30
2011-12-22 08:00
2011-12-22 08:30
2011-12-22 09:00
2011-12-22 09:30
2011-12-22 10:00
2011-12-22 10:30
2011-12-22 11:00
2011-12-22 11:30
```

Is possible this with loop FOR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php
$interval = 1800; // Interval in seconds

$date_first     = "2011-12-22 07:00";
$date_second    = "2011-12-22 11:30";

$time_first     = strtotime($date_first);
$time_second    = strtotime($date_second);

for ($i = $time_first; $i < $time_second; $i += $interval)
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $i) . "<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
$dates = array();
$start = new DateTime($one);
$until = new DateTime($two);

while($start->getTimestamp() <= $until->getTimestamp()) {

   $dates[] = clone $start;
   $start->add(new DateInterval("PT30M"));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dates);
```

Comment: The interval specification for DateInterval should be "PT30M" for 30 mins interval. P30M is for 30 months.

Answer (score 2):

See how you go with this..

```
$one = strtotime('2011-12-22 07:00');
$two = strtotime('2011-12-22 11:30');

while($two>$one){
    $interval_timestamp = $one += 60*30;
    echo date('r',$interval_timestamp);//output as needed.
}
```

Comment: I suggest you split it into multiple lines, especially the `echo date` line is counterintuitive.